# Conditional expression for Background color in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, conditional-statements, expression

I have a matrix in my SSRS 2016 reporting services report.  I am trying to set a conditional expression on background color for the sum(field.value).  This field is formatted as a percent.  Here is my expression which does not appear to have any errors:

Background Color Expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value<.80,"Red",Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value >= .80 and Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value < .95,"Yellow",Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value >= .95,"lightGreen")
```

Problem:  It turns everything "lightgreen" even when their textbox should be yellow's and red's in the matrix.  there is one field that is highlighted as Red, but it should have been Yellow.

I tried to set this in the field property for background color expression.  That just made everything "light green".

I changed it to the fill expression in the matrix Text box.  Now I get mostly everything green except the one red field that should be yellow. I checked my numeric values and they are coming across in decimals points when I change the format back to number

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mention in your your comment that you are doing it for the sum(field.value) why aren't you using the same in the color expression as well?

Answer (score 0):

As Harry mentioned in the comments, you need to be evaluating the same expression as you are displaying.

Also you can simplify the SWITCH statement as follows.

```
=SWITCH(
        SUM(Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value) <.80, "Red",
        SUM(Fields!PicturesbeforeFirstSignoutCount.Value) < 0.95, "Yellow",
        True ,"LightGreen"
        )
```

As `SWITCH` returns the first result where the expression is true, there is no need to put a range in. so if the value was 0.91 then the first expression would be skipped but the second one would be true to it would return "Yellow".

The final `True` acts as an "else".